# Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module

Tags: gulp, autoprefixer

Когда подключаю gulp-autoprefixer и запускаю код выходит эта ошибка:
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module

```
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
function styles() {
return src(['app/scss/style.scss'])
    .pipe(autoprefixer({ overrideBrowserslist: ['last 10 version'] }))
    .pipe(concat('style.min.css'))
    .pipe(scss({ outputStyle: 'compressed' }))
    .pipe(dest('app/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Если проблема с `gulp-autoprefixer`, то напиши в консоль:

```
npm i --save-dev gulp-autoprefixer@7.0.0
```

Это должно решить твою проблему, а вообще советую узнать после какой строки появляется данная ошибка.